# Can I manually activate my follower's skills?

Tags: diablo-iii

My Templar follower has a skill that lets him heal me, which I was hoping would be good in extended fights against strong enemies.  However, he doesn't seem to care that I'm taking damage, and only seems to want to heal me if there's nothing around that needs stabbing/murder.

Is there any way I can tell my follower "Hey, you, heal me *now!*" or something similar?

Comment: It's probably on cool down. It's a full 90 seconds, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a way to manually trigger followers' abilities.

According to Blizzard's Follower FAQ ([archived here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Followers_FAQ)):

> **Will you be able to control the followers?**
>
> No, we've avoided pet and
> follower commands as they added unnecessary micromanagement to the
> game.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in the very beginning with the Templar that in fact has a very useful ability, but it seems that this is completely automatically and cannot be forced in anyway.