# Am I missing out on anything by staying faithful to my follower?

Tags: diablo-iii

My Templar and I have an arrangement - "till death do we part, and even then just until we respawn."  We've been through a lot, but I can always count on him to throw a heal on me if the demons have been getting me down.  Well, not [*always*...](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67068/can-i-manually-activate-my-followers-skills)

I've more or less left the other two followers in town for most of the game.  I don't really have any intention of taking them anytime soon as well.  I talk to them, of course, and get all their dialog options, but it's just *not the same.*

Are there any achievements or custom dialog that I can only gain by spending more time with other followers, or taking them into specific situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some achievements linked to followers but **nothing that requires to spend a minimum amount of time with them**, at least for now.

Achievements that involve follower are:

- A Guilding Light: Use the Templar as a follower.
- Me, Myself and Eirena: Use the Enchantress as a follower.
- Stolen Moments: Use the Scoundrel as a follower.
- The Art of Conversation: Complete the main character, follower, and artisan conversation achievements
- Friends with Benefits: Fully equip one of your followers.
- For the Order: Listen to all Templar's conversations.
- To Catch a Thief: Listen to all Scoundrel's conversations.
- Secret of the Ages: Listen to all Enchantress's conversations.