# Is there a penalty for switching followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm a fickle person, and would like to switch my followers around according to my mood.

Is there any reason—besides the inconvenience of traveling back to town—why I couldn't? Am I penalized for switching? Is there some sort of rate limiting?

Comment: I saw your [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36671/how-much-can-my-follower-carry/36734#36734) about Skyrim's follower carry limits, this question made me chuckle with irony.

Comment: Seems related to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67935/am-i-missing-out-on-anything-by-staying-faithful-to-my-follower, just the exact opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a one - they even automatically level to stay one level under you when you aren't using them.

Comment: Answered in 47 seconds? *golf clap*

Comment: Sometimes you're just sitting around being unproductive, and you see that (1) pop up on your New questions tab, and well..

Answer (score 0):

I have had my followers gain levels by dropping them and then picking them back up.  I can't remember how they fell behind me, but when I picked them back up they jumped up to 1 below my level.