# Which skills is the Scoundrel using?

Tags: diablo-iii

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67070/36981) answer indicates that it is not possible to specifically activate follower skills. Does this mean that the follower (a level 27 Scoundrel in my case) will choose which of this four skills to use? Does he switch between the four, or just use the level 20 skill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He uses them to his hearts content or when he deems it necessary. All the available skills will be used but the player can't really do anything to "time" the best moment to use a certain skill. This can make some of the skills with longer cool downs bad or at the very best situational.

Comment: Posted 7 seconds after Raven Dreamer. I'll accept yours :)

Answer (score 3):

The follower will use all 4 of the skills you select. Depending on the follower, some of these may be passives or have conditional activations, but picking higher-tier skills does not prevent the follower from using the lower-tier skills as well.